# Weekly scheduled AMI backup of an Amazon EC2 instance with a root volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have DB instances in my AWS account. Many volumes are attached to one instance. I want to create an [AMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Machine_Image) of an Amazon EC2 instance with a root volume on weekly basis. At any point of time I should have the latest AMIs for an instance.

I have tried with systems manager. It’s creating snapshots of all volumes attached with the instance.

I have written a Bash script to create an AMI of an instance with a root volume. I need an approach to delete older images.

Note: The instance should not reboot the AMI creation

How can I update the script or is there is another way
to achieve it?

```
#!/bin/bash
root_device=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-12345 --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].RootDeviceName' --output text)
echo root device is $root_device
devices=$(for i in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-12345 --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].BlockDeviceMappings[*].DeviceName' --output text );
do if [ $i != $root_device ];
  then echo  DeviceName=$i,NoDevice=;
  fi;
done)

aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-12345 --block-device-mappings $devices --name "test-ami" --no-reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a lambda function to create an AMI on a weekly basis. That solved my problem.

Another advantage is irrespective of the OS, I can use the function take AMI. :)

Comment: That is not of much help to future readers unless you [reveal](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69686846/edit) some more information, for example, the function itself.